# No $route on this in a vuejs component. what's wrong?

Tags: vuejs2

I'm beginner with vuejs.
I started my first vuejs component on a single file .vue.

I wanted to get the param of a route. But "this" doesn't have $route. this is Window.
Somebody can help me to understand ?

In main.js, I configured the router with :

```
var Vue = require('vue');
var VueRouter = require('vue-router');

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const Home = require('./components/home.vue');
const Songbook = require('./components/songbook.vue');

var router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [{
        path: '/',
        component: Home
    }, {
        path: '/songbook/:userId',
        component: Songbook
    }]
});

const app = new Vue({
    router: router,
    el : '#app',
    template : '<router-view></router-view>'
});
```

In songbook.vue, where I hope use userId on this.$route.params, I have :

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>Songbook</h1>
</div>
</template>

<script>

var getPlaylists = function() {
  console.log(this);
};

getPlaylists();

module.exports = {
    data: function() {
        return {
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The console.log(this) give me the window object, not an object with $route. I don't see where is the problem... SOS :-)

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the `getPlaylist` function is just a regular function and not bound to the `this` keyword. Even though it might be counter-intuitive at first glance, Vue can only bind the component's context to methods in the exported config object (`module.exports = { ... }`), so `this` will be available e.g. inside the `data` function but not in `getPlaylist`.

If you really need `this` in functions outside of the config object, you'll have to do something like this:

```
<script>
    var getPlaylists = function() {
      console.log(this);
    };

    module.exports = {
        data: function() {
            getPlaylists.call(this); // supply context to getPlaylists()
            return { };
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you ! C'est complètement logique.

Comment: @Manu Could you accept my answer if it solves your problem?